# How to configure a shutdown at the xth wrong entered password?

Tags: security, login, encryption, pam, luks

> Having an encrypted hard drive is all well and good, but chances are that if someone is gonna steal your laptop, it’s probably not going to be turned off. Most likely, it will be stolen in a powered-on state. And so your encrypted hard drive doesn’t increase your security at all since it’s currently unlocked.

This is how [this blog article](https://cowboyprogrammer.org/2016/09/reboot_machine_on_wrong_password/) explains the problem and the setup on Debian.
A good solution may thus be to shutdown the device, when you have entered the wrong user-unlock password for e.g. 4 times.

However, I e.g. struggle to even find the `common-auth` or `common-account` in `/etc/pam.d` in my system there. (Fedora) Also, I guess, the article could be a little outdated or maybe not the best solution. And as I have not found this question being asked here already, I thought I'd better ask.

So in general: **How do I configure an automatic shutdown after the x-th wrong entered password?**

Note this is a security-requirement, so you should not e.g. not be able to cancel the shutdown. Also, it would be a little bad if you e.g. count for each user to 3, you should actually better have some global counter, so the attacker cannot switch to another user for trying their login first.

---

Cross-posted [at AskFedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/how-to-configure-a-shutdown-at-the-xth-wrong-entered-password/928?u=rugk).

Comment: Side note, a wrong password should already be forcing a ≈1s delay. If someone can crack your password at 1 try per second then you need a better password. (Though this may still make sense as a defense-in-depth approach.)

Comment: From the blog script ...`chmod 777 "${COUNTFILE}"` .... This seems wrong and *mildly* insecure.

Comment: @derobert It certainly makes sense, because I consider that users use a much longer (and harder to brute-force) password for luks than the simple login password. (And when you can shutdown, you force them to attack the long password.)

Comment: @rugk wiping the LUKS header may also make sense. Also, LUKS password had better be stronger, at least another 6+ random letters/numbers because it's an offline attack, so much faster guessing possible. At least with a budget. (of course, someone with a budget will have much better attacks on the booted laptop).

Answer (score 2):

2023 solution working on ubuntu with **pam_faillock** (pam_tally2 is deprecated):

**Careful, you can lock yourself up**: Editing pam files will take effect instantly and it is more likely than not that you will break authentication a couples times during the process. Don't proceed if you are not comfortable with that. A few things to spare you a lot of trouble;

- Pre-open and pre-login in a root tty (`ctrl + alt + f3`)
- Backup any files before editing them (e.g. `cp /etc/pam.d/common-auth ~/common-auth.bak`)
- Have a live boot USB key on hand

In `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=ok ignore=ignore default=bad] pam_faillock.so deny=3 even_deny_root unlock_time=10
auth    required pam_exec.so /usr/sbin/poweroff
auth    [success=3 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_sss.so use_first_pass
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
# end of pam-auth-update config
auth    sufficient pam_faillock.so authsucc
```

**Detailed explanation**:

First be aware that `success=n` means `skip the next n lines if the current line succeeds`. This is used both to trigger the poweroff only when the faillock condition is met, but also to determine when faillock should register a failed or successful login attempt.

The following two lines trigger the poweroff after 3 failed attempts.

```
auth    [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=ok ignore=ignore default=bad] pam_faillock.so deny=3 even_deny_root unlock_time=10
auth    required pam_exec.so /usr/sbin/poweroff
```

Then you have the pre-existing ubuntu authentication logic with `success=3` and `success=2` respectively, that were edited to skip both the pre-existing pam_deny stuff but also one new line for pam_faillock.

```
auth    [success=3 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_sss.so use_first_pass
```

Then you have this line, which tells pam_faillock to register a failed login attempt. This line is skipped if the previous pam_unix logic passes.

```
auth    [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail
```

And finally at the end, if nothing in the config marked the login attempt as failed, we instruct pam_faillock to register a successful login attempt. This is critical as otherwise, pam_faillock would never reset.

```
auth    sufficient pam_faillock.so authsucc
```

Side note; I'm a pam noob so take my explanations with a grain of salt. But this does work on my setup.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **pam_tally2** and **pam_exec** to achieve this result.

If you add the following at the beginning of `/etc/pam.d/login`, the system should shutdown on the 6th attempt after 5 failed logins.

```
auth [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=ok ignore=ignore default=bad] pam_tally2.so onerr=succeed deny=5 even_deny_root unlock_time=30
auth required pam_exec.so /usr/bin/poweroff
```

- success=1 skips the next line preventing the shutdown of the system if pam_tally2 succeeds.
- unlock_time=30 unlocks the account automatically after 30 seconds in order to prevent a permanent lockout of your root account.

Note: If you use a display manager (like GDM, LightDM, etc.) you probably need to add a similar rule to the respective PAM-configuration (possible without `even_deny_root` and `unloock_time`, if you don't allow graphical root login).

Answer (score 0):

Besides the PAM option, there is also the possibility of using the logs.Now, I switched from Fedora to Slackware, so the exact files may be wrong, but if you put something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f /tmp/erlogin ] ; then
    oldvalue=$(cat /tmp/erlogin)
    newvalue=$(grep 'invalid password' /var/log/secure|wc -l)
    if [ $((newvalue-oldvalue)) -gt 3 ] ; then
        shutdown -h now
    fi
fi
grep 'invalid password' /var/log/secure|wc -l> /tmp/erlogin
```

And that every 10 minutes or so.

Comment: Nice idea and short script, however a) you are missing some clear instructions on how to setup. (but that is probably not that bad) b) of course, there is a interval until the script triggers, which allows more than three guesses if you are fast and c) the file `/var/log/secure` actually did _not_ exist in my Fedora system here.