# Shutdown after X failed login attempts

Tags: ubuntu, security, login, pam

I have a laptop with Xubuntu 22.10, whose SSD is encrypted with LUKS, so if it's stolen when shut down, my data should be safe. But it's more likely to be stolen while it's switched on, and then only the lock screen protects the data. So, I'd like to be able to set a maximum number of login attempts before the laptop shuts down and the LUKS key has to be re-entered.

I understand that pam_tally2 is deprecated, so I tried to mix [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572770) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403438/how-do-i-set-up-pam-faillock) to add this in `/etc/pam.d/login`, but it didn't work. First, it had no effect on graphical login, and second, it caused an immediate shutdown on first login attempt on tty.

```
auth required pam_faillock.so preauth audit silent deny=3 unlock_time=900
auth required pam_exec.so /sbin/poweroff
```

Sorry if it sounds like a newbie-question. I could find how to "lock" a user but not how to trigger a command or script instead (a shutdown in my case). I'd like it to work both for tty or graphical login. How could such a thing be done?
Thank you in advance!